# Cordova - opening the InAppBrowser without checking for a network connection (Apple Approval)

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm not entirely sure why I feel this way, perhaps something I read at some point, but my understanding is that while providing an offline experience within an app, it is my responsibility to appropriately manage situations where my app requires an internet connection and one is not available (a proper alert for example).

When opening an external website using the Cordova InAppBrowser, if there is no internet connection, am i required to do something about it, or is the error appearing in the webview of the plugin enough? Will this interfere with the approval process, or is this entirely ok?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out Dom.

http://gtproductions.net/blog/ways-to-get-rejected-by-apple-app-store-tips/

point 4 seems to point out that apps  (games here) may get rejected if connection issues are not properly handled.